# Want to Use images from project/public/images folder to card inside src/pages/home.js

Tags: reactjs, image, dictionary, public

I want to use images from project/public/images/ to my card inside src/pages/home.js using map function. When I try to use map function it shows error
How do I solve this problem

I  to made a js file  name data js where I give path bur it shows error how can I give path of images inside public/images/ inside data js and use it in home page

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what error you are getting, nor do i fully understand your problem.
If you ask how to use images in your jsx:

```
import logo from "../public/images/logo.png"

const home = () => {

   return (
      <img src={logo} /> 
   )

}
```

If i misunderstood your problem please supply your code and the error message you are getting

Answer (score 0):

To access images from the image directory in your public folder do this:

```
<img src="/images/image.png" />
```

replace `image.png` with the filename of the image you want to use.